# About pointer to multidimension array

Tags: c, pointers

I read this from a book: for `double beans[3][4]`

if we want to make a pointer called it `pbeans` to point to it we need to declare it as

```
double (*pbeans) [4] =beans;
```

My question is:

1. Why it is:

   `double (*pbeans) [4] =beans`;

   but not:

   `double[4] *pbeans =beans`;  ?
2. And how should I read `double (*pbeans) [4]` ? 
   (say, const int `* const pi` we can read from right to left const pointer to integer constant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why it is `double (*pbeans) [4] =beans;` but not `double[4] *pbeans =beans;` ?

This is because you need pointer to the first element of array `beans` and the first element of it is an 1D array of 4 elements.
Why not `double[4] *pbeans =beans;`?

Because this is not a valid C syntax.

> And how should I read  `double (*pbeans) [4]`? (say, `const int * const pi` we can read from right to left const pointer to integer constant).

You can read this as *`pbeans` is a pointer to an array of `4` `doubles`s. You can use [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) to parse such declarations.

Answer (score 1):

C declaration syntax is based on the types of *expressions*, not objects.  This is also phrased as "declaration mimics use."

You have a pointer to a 4-element array of `double` named `pbeans`.  To access an element from the pointed-to array, you must first dereference `pbeans` using the unary `*` operator, and then apply the subscript to the result of that dereference:

```
double x = (*pbeans)[i];
```

The parentheses are necessary because the subscript operator `[]` has higher precedence than unary `*` operator; if you wrote `*pbeans[i]`, it would be parsed as `*(pbeans[i])`, which would attempt to dereference the result of `pbeans[i]`, which is not what we want.

The type of the *expression* `(*pbeans)[i]` is `double`, so it follows that the declaration of `pbeans` is

```
double (*pbeans)[4];
```

The decalration is read as

```
         pbeans         -- pbeans
       (*pbeans)        -- is a pointer to
       (*pbeans)[4]     -- a 4-element array
double (*pbeans)[4];    -- of double.
```

Answer (score 0):

1) It is the format in C to declare arrays using,

```
datatype name[][];
```

format. here

```
double (*pbeans) [4] =beans;
```

means `pbeans` is a array of 4 items and where each item is of type `double *` i.e. a pointer to double.

2)you read

```
const int * const pi
```

from right to left as `pi is a constant pointer to a integer constant`